How to use "TypedHttpClientFactory" with "AddHttpMessageHandler"?
I have some AuthorizationHandler that I register with a typed client:
    var clientFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    services.AddHttpClient<TypedClient>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            var authorization = new BearerAuthorization(clientFactory, clientId, clientSecret, authHost, token);
            return new AuthorizationHandler(authorization);
        });

When I get the "TypedClient" directly through the DI container, everything works fine and the AuthorizationHandler handler is called before the request, for example, like this:
    _typedClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TypedClient>();
    await _typedClient.SendRequest(); // OK

BUT. When trying to get this client from the ITypedHttpClientFactory factory, the handler stops being called, which gives an authorization error:
    _httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    _typedClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TypedClient>>();
    using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    using var typedClient = _typedClientFactory.CreateClient(client);

    await typedClient.SendRequest(); // Fail

How do I get a typed client from the factory that will have the added handler called before the request?

Why do you want to use ITypedHttpClientFactory?

This is expected, as the ITypedHttpClientFactory documentation states:

The default ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient> uses type activation to create typed client instances. Typed client types are not retrieved directly from the IServiceProvider. See CreateInstance(IServiceProvider, Type, Object[]) for details.

So, here's answer to your question:

Typed client types are not retrieved directly from the IServiceProvider.


In that case, if I want to wrap the client in a handler, then I can't use the factory at all?

It looks like so

One way to solve this problem is to inject a named client into the typed client via the ITypedHttpClientFactory's CreateClient method. Whenever you fetch a named HttpClient then it will retrieve it from the DI with all of its DelegatingHandlers.
Here you can find a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wC4Neg
Service registrations
ServiceCollection collection  = new();
collection.AddTransient<TestDelegatingHandler>();
collection.AddHttpClient();
collection.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClient>("test")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetService<TestDelegatingHandler>());


Here we register a dummy DelegatingHandler into the DI container first
Then we register the default HttpClient factories
Finally we register a typed client which is named test

Here we add the MessageHandler to the named client



Client creations
ServiceProvider provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
IHttpClientFactory namedFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
ITypedHttpClientFactory<TypedClient> typedFactory  = provider.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TypedClient>>();

HttpClient namedClient = namedFactory.CreateClient("test");
TypedClient typedClient = typedFactory.CreateClient(namedClient); 


First we build the ServiceCollection
Then we retrieve an IHttpClientFactory and an ITypedHttpClientFactory service
Thirdly we fetch the named client .CreateClient("test")

This client is decorated with the dummy DelegatingHandler


Finally we create a TypedClient instance via the ITypedHttpClientFactory by injecting the previously fetched named HttpClient

Supporting structures
public interface ITypedClient
{
    Task GetAsync();
}

public class TypedClient: ITypedClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public TypedClient(HttpClient client) => _client = client;
    
    public async Task GetAsync() => await _client.GetAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
}

public class TestDelegatingHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        "Hello".Dump();
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

